# How to require ActionCable to React frontend in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, websocket, actioncable

I know that it is easy to integrate React app with ActionCable using asset pipeline. But is there a good way to integrate it with separate components located in

```
app/javascript/components
```

For example we have *notifications_channel* located in

```
app/javascripts/channels
```

by default. But I need to handle WebSocket data in my React app located in

```
app/javasctipt
```